# How to express "elements that belong to two or more sets but not to their intersection"?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a symbol to express the following?

> > *Elements that belong to two or more sets but not to their intersection; elements uncommon to all sets*.

I know that for sets $A$ and $B$, $A\cap B$ is the intersection of $A$ and $B$ to denote elements common to both $A$ and $B$. Also, $\#A$ and $\#B$ represents the cardinal number of $A$ and $B$ (number of elements in $A$ and $B$). And $A\cup B$ just joins the two sets together, represented by a *Venn-diagram*.

However, what symbol is there to express what is written in the yellow box?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The formatting could be better, but I don’t understand the downvotes…

Comment: Also, the cardinality of a set is just about universally written $\lvert S\rvert$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor alright then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set you are talking about looks like the one below,
then this is called the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), which is sometimes denoted $$A \triangle B.$$

[image: symmetric difference]

Comment: Thanks heaps!! Just what I need! Congratulations :) $$(+1) \ \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$